# Photon Path Distinguishability and Optical Coherence: a Paradox?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, double-slit-experiment

When a photon's path in an interferometer is knowable by some means, there will be no interference in the interferometer output.  Conversely, I think that it is true that loss of interference implies that there is some way to know which path the photon took in the interferometer, although you would have to figure out where to find this info.

Here is a situation that seems to contradict this:  imagine you have a polarized point source of light with, for example, a rectangular frequency spectrum about some average frequency.  It follows that its temporal amplitude-amplitude coherence function has the form of a sinc function.  Consequently, using this source in a Young's experiment with very narrow slits, there are points on the observation screen where the fringe visibility vanishes, corresponding to the zeros of that sinc function.

At the first sinc zero, you have lost interference and thus should be able to determine, with complete certainty, which slit a photon went through. *But how?* WHERE is this information?  That is the question.

Before you say 'photon arrival time information', keep in mind that there is still a lot of interference going on to either side of this screen point.  So there is something special there, and only there, that reveals, with complete certainty, which slit a photon came from.  But what?

I even add that, if you use a wavepacket model, you find that there is still a good deal of overlap in the temporal wavepackets from the two slits as they are superposed, with relative time delay, at that screen point.   This appears to make complete which-slit distinguishability hopeless, at least using arrival time.  So how can you know, with certainty, which slit a particular photon came from?

Comment: Are you proposing that a zero on the screen implies no interference?  If there is a zero on the screen, then that is evidence that there is interference.  Otherwise, there would not be a zero.  If you mean something else, you'll have to clarify your statement.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the precise calculation that makes you think the fringe visibility vanishes? Your main inference (that a local lack of interference implies the presence of which-way information) is wrong, but knowing exactly what you're thinking will help write a more relatable answer.

Comment: garyp, my question refers to a zero in fringe contrast, not in the intensity on the screen.  In other words, there is intensity there, but the fringes are gone at that point, although they are present at other points on the screen.

Comment: Emilio, details are less important, but you address the essence of my question.  Specifically you say I am wrong in my implication that a *local* lack of interference implies the presence of which-way information.   Can you prove, or provide a reference addressing that statement? A contradictory statement seems to be in Mandel, Opt. Lett. 16 1882 (1991). Here, a lack of fringes implies distinguishability. I admit I am applying to a special point on Young's screen, although it looks like Mandel's arguments would still apply.

Comment: Fringe visibility is about the difference in observed maxima and minima of intensity, it is not about whether you happen to see something at a particular point in an interference pattern, see http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/FringeVisibility.html

Answer (score 0):

Although knowledge of which path the photon took would lead to the lack of interference, I don't think that the converse is necessarily true. It could be that the light entering the interferometer is incoherence, which in a sense is what you are assuming. Moreover, because the phenomenon that you describe is produced by the spectral properties of the light, nothing prevents you from sticking a wavelength filter into the light after the interferometer and thus recovering the interference. So the information, if we can call it that must still be present in the light.